# For loop returning 0 from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, foreach

I want to calculate cointegration to all the tickets.

So we start with stock A and then calculate cointegration with STOCK B, C, D, E, etc .

Then we start with stock B, and it cointegration with stock C,D,E,etc

But the loop it's returning 0. What is the error ?

**Importing data**

```
tickets = ['MMM',
 'ABT',
 'ABBV',
 'ABMD',
 'ACN',
 'ATVI',
 'ADBE',
 'AMD']

data = {tick: yf.download(tick, start = "2017-06-14", end = "2021-06-14", interval="1d")['Adj Close'] for tick in tickets}
```

**Making the loop**

```
lista = []
comprimento = len(tickets)

for i in range(0, comprimento):
    print("Ticket a ser analisado: " + str(tickets[i]))
   
    for j in range(i+1, comprimento):
           
        cointeracao = coint(data[i], data[j])
        if cointeracao[1] < 0.05:
            lista.append((tickets[i],tickets[j]))
            print(lista)
            
lista
```

**Error :**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-f15c6a752928> in <module>
      7     for j in range(i+1, comprimento):
      8 
----> 9         cointeracao = coint(data[i], data[j])
     10         if cointeracao[1] < 0.05:
     11             lista.append((tickets[i],tickets[j]))

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: `coint(data[i], data[j])` should throw an error, the keys in `data` are strings from `tickets`, not integers. Please explain more clearly what is the actual issue.

Comment: So i need to make them to be integers? thats the error ?

Comment: I want to calculate cointegration to all the variables. So we start with stock A and then calculate cointegration with STOCK B, C, D, E, etc . Then we start with stock B, and it cointegration with stock C,D,E,etc and it does this to all of the tickers

Comment: Try `data[tickets[i]], data[tickets[j]]`

Comment: this is it! thank you so much